# IBM Watson Visual Recognition module

Tags: android, rest, ibm-cloud, visual-recognition

I have developed an Android app that send REST directives directly to the Visual Recognition service in IBM Bluemix.

If I send a photograph that shows a female subject, Watson responds with a proper identification.

But if I send one, with the very same application, of a male subject, Watson does not even analyze it.

I am not trying to classify. I just want to identify faces in a photo.

Can anybody tell me if the Watson Visual Recognition service that I am accessing is only trained to identify women?. (joking) Is there something I am missing when I send the POST Rest directive?

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS.

I am a registered user in the Bluemix platform and I have proper credentials to access the Visual Recognition service.

The app was developed in the MIT App inventor platform. It works OK for female photos, but not with male ones.

Comment: Without code how are we supposed to help?

Comment: Please provide the code so the team can determine what might be causing the problem. Without that code, we cannot help.